# Can I set Firebug breakpoints in jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, firebug, jsfiddle

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is often used to illustrate and test here on SO. When I test/develop javascript I use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) *a lot* - breakpoints are my friends. Has anyone figured out a way of setting Firebug breakpoints in their jsFiddle test code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571128/javascript-debugging-in-html-file

Answer (score 14):

**[updated]**

yes. it's the fiddle.hshell.net/show in the drop-down list of js files used when you select the scripts tab.

**[updated 2]**

seems to be in `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/` now

**[update 3]**

You can use `debugger;` to add breakpoints to your JS.
[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/F3WmG/)

Comment: I tried that one, but I don't get it to break. Could this be a Firebug 1.6.0 problem?

Comment: i tried with firebug 1.6 and it worked for me. Doubtful but figured I'd ask, you didn't set it at a comment or if/then that wasn't triggered did you?

Comment: It seems to be located in fiddle.jshell.net now.

Comment: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/` -> `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`. I can't cut and paste into chrome when using synergy and firefox sucks for just testing a little javascript code. aaarggghhh!